# Azure Schedule WebJob settings

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-webjobs

How can I run a webjob based off of settings.json instead of hardcoded value in TimerTrigger?

settings.json

```
{
  //Runs at 9:30 AM every day
  "schedule": "0 30 9 * * *"
}
```

Functions.cs

```
[Singleton]
public static void TimerTick([TimerTrigger("0 * * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Hello at {DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()}");
}
```

It always uses the hard coded value:
The next 5 occurrences of **the schedule (Cron: '0 * * * * *')**

** will be:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to do that is explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#ncrontab-expressions):

> You can put the schedule expression in an app setting and set this property to the app setting name wrapped in % signs, as in this example: "%ScheduleAppSetting%".

So, in your case it would be something like this:

settings.json

```
{
  //Runs at 9:30 AM every day
  "schedule": "0 30 9 * * *"
}
```

Functions.cs

```
[Singleton]
public static void TimerTick([TimerTrigger("%schedule%")] TimerInfo myTimer)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Hello at {DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()}");
}
```

Comment: You are referirng to Azure functions? I think this question is about webjobs.

Comment: @Enrico they share the same techniques, the answer applies to both. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#ncrontab-expressions. Edit: to prevent confusion I updated the link.